# Failed to retrieve directory listing with filezila

Tags: filezilla

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.bdtourbazar.com
Status: Connecting to 173.254.62.212:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 11 of 1000 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 01:12. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER imran@bdtourbazar.com
Response:   331 User imran@bdtourbazar.com OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ************
Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extensions supported:
Response:    EPRT
Response:    IDLE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MFMT
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;
Response:    MLSD
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    ESTA
Response:    PASV
Response:    EPSV
Response:    SPSV
Response:    ESTP
Response:   211 End.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PORT 175,29,183,110,23,115
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Could not open data connection to port 6003: Connection refused
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Response:   421 Timeout - try typing a little faster next time
Error:  Connection closed by server
Status: Resolving address of ftp.bdtourbazar.com
Status: Connecting to 173.254.62.212:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 12 of 1000 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 01:32. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER bdtourba
Response:   331 User bdtourba OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ****************
Response:   530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A dump can provide supplemental information, but you need to explain all of the specifics--exactly what were you trying to do? How were you trying to do it? exactly what problems did you experience?  What kind of connection?  Relevant settings? etc.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess - you're using the wrong password for the user "bdtourba".  That and your server is refusing connections on port 6003.

As for what to do about it - without knowing what FTP server software you are using, I can't begin to make a guess.

Check your password in your FTP client (if this is filezilla, go into site manager) and check whch port you should be connecting on.

Answer (score 0):

Set your ftp client to use "Passive mode"